# How to set table-width dynamically, dependent on width of browser window

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to adjust table-width to the browser window width after every resize-event, and dynamically adjust the column-widths accordingly?

Example: Window width = 1900px displaying a table, table-width = 1500px, with 5 columns at 300px. Now the browser window is resized to 1600px. Table width should now be 1265px, and each col.253px.

Thanks for feedback, Matt

Answer (score 0):

You can set the table to be relative to the viewport-width:

```css
table {
  width: 85vw; // so 85% of the window's width

  td {
    width: 20%; // each column taking up 20% = 5 columns of the total table width
  }
}
```